# Email client with gmail, (business) office365 without imap?

Tags: email, office365

What I thought to be trivial turned out to be far from it, or at least in my experience.
I have a gmail-account for my personal email and have been using that for years. For my work we have Office65-accounts, which I could add to gmail with imap/smtp. I did that in the gmail web-app and did that on my phone, worked fine. However, company policy has been updated recently to disable smtp/imap for mail; only OAuth2 is still supported.

So now I'm looking for a mail client which supports both. I've tried Newton for the past few weeks, but it isn't very stable for me, such as archived mail on my laptop still appearing in my inbox on my phone. And the window behaves odd in Gnome.

I installed Edison on my phone yesterday which seems to work fine. I wanted to try Geary on my laptop today, but apparently it doesn't support office365 (without imap/smtp).

I'm willing to use a paid application on both Android/Linux, as long as it integrates with everything smooth. I would highly prefer not to use Thunderbird though, the interface looks horrible to me. I also only want mail, no calendar-integration needed.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same problem I faced, but it sounds familiar.  When my workplace made the switch, they didn't care about the few Ubuntu users.  But I found out if you accept Thunderbird (it's not that bad...), then you need to purchase `Owl for Exchange`.  See [here](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/owl-for-exchange/).  You pay once per e-mail account, not per computer that you use it on.  And their technical support is ok -- they reply within a day.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I found that option, but Thunderbird is just such a horrible UI... I don't think I could stand it for very long... Thanks either way for your suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome!  I think when I decided, it was the choice between Thunderbird or the web-based Outlook that my workplace's IT people is forcing on us.  It was the lesser of two evils for me...  Hopefully someone else can offer you an alternative; I might look into it myself...  Good luck!

Comment: Curently I'm trying out Spike which seems to be working fine. Except that I'd have to pay $12/month after the trail period, which I think is quite expensive for just a mail client.. So still looking for alternatives